# Merge raster layers error

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-processing, saga, mosaic

Is there an issue with the SAGA-tool "Mosaicking rasters"?
I tried it with different rasters. In Sage itself it works fine.

> Algorithmus Mosaick raster layers startet...
>   io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "C:\Temp\processing\04593242dc054133b9fbcae916bae1f8\1tif.sgrd" -FILES "C:\Temp\test\2.tif,C:\Temp\test\1.tif"
>   grid_tools "Mosaicking" -TARGET 0 -GRIDS "C:\Temp\processing\04593242dc054133b9fbcae916bae1f8\1tif.sgrd" -TYPE 7 -INTERPOL 0 -OVERLAP 1 -BLEND_DIST 10 -MATCH 0 -USER_FIT 0 -USER_XMIN 331858.3 -USER_XMAX 335568.9 -USER_YMIN 5921607.7 -USER_YMAX 5924629.6 -USER_GRID "C:\Temp\processing\0aab6cedcd08418eab5e1ee4eca47901\USERGRID.sdat"
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin>set SAGA=C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\saga
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\saga\modules
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin>PATH=PATH;C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\saga;C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\saga\modules
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin>saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "C:\Temp\processing\04593242dc054133b9fbcae916bae1f8\1tif.sgrd" -FILES "C:\Temp\test\2.tif,C:\Temp\test\1.tif"
>   ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
>   127: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
>   ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
>   127: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
>   ERROR 4: `C:\Temp\test\2.tif,C:\Temp\test\1.tif' does not exist in the file system,
>   and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
>   library path: C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\saga\modules\io_gdal.dll
>   library name: Import/Export - GDAL/OGR
>   tool name : GDAL: Import Raster
>   author : O.Conrad (c) 2007 A.Ringeler)
>   Parameters
>   Grids: No objects
>   Files: "C:\Temp\test\2.tif,C:\Temp\test\1.tif"
>   Transformation: yes
>   Interpolation: Nearest Neighbor
>   loading: C:\Temp\test\2.tif,C:\Temp\test\1.tif
>   failed: could not find a suitable import driver
>   Error: Dataset creation failed:`C:\Temp\test\2.tif,C:\Temp\test\1.tif' does not exist in the file system,
>   and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
>   Error: executing tool [GDAL: Import Raster]
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin>saga_cmd grid_tools "Mosaicking" -TARGET 0 -GRIDS "C:\Temp\processing\04593242dc054133b9fbcae916bae1f8\1tif.sgrd" -TYPE 7 -INTERPOL 0 -OVERLAP 1 -BLEND_DIST 10 -MATCH 0 -USER_FIT 0 -USER_XMIN 331858.3 -USER_XMAX 335568.9 -USER_YMIN 5921607.7 -USER_YMAX 5924629.6 -USER_GRID "C:\Temp\processing\0aab6cedcd08418eab5e1ee4eca47901\USERGRID.sdat"
>   ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
>   127: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
>   ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
>   127: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
>   library path: C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\saga\modules\grid_tools.dll
>   library name: Grid - Tools
>   tool name : Mosaicking
>   author : O.Conrad (c) 2003-12
>   Load grid: C:\Temp\processing\04593242dc054133b9fbcae916bae1f8\1tif.sgrd...
>   failed
>   Mosaicking: could not initialize data objects
>   Error: Grid file could not be opened.
>   Error: executing tool [Mosaicking]
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin>exit
>   Converting outputs
>   Lade Ergebnis Layer

Comment: It looks like the command tries to find one file named as "C:\Temp\test\2.tif,C:\Temp\test\1.tif" instead of two files "C:\Temp\test\2.tif" and "C:\Temp\test\1.tif". I do not know SAGA but based on tutorial http://vorboss.dl.sourceforge.net/project/saga-gis/SAGA%20-%20Documentation/Tutorials/Command_Line_Scripting/scripting_saga.pdf the filenames should perhaps be separated by semicolon ;

Comment: Could you please try it on your system?

Comment: I may have tried SAGA sometimes but I have never really used it and I do not have QGIS + SAGA installed at the moment. Let's hope some other friendly people will have a look at this.

Comment: Might be a bug in the processing tool box.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try wildcards: "C:\Temp\test\*.tif"